# Scraping from google images always stops at 51st element despite sharing the same xpaths

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to learn the basics of web scraping and machine learning by following some tutorials and what not. After some tinkering, I managed to get the script to work for the most part, but it seems to always stop at the 51st image no matter what I do, and will be thrown into my "XPath not found" error. The tutorial I followed makes us check between the thumbnail and the high rez images, and download only the high rez images. I fixed a prior issue where there were multiple xpaths for the high rez images, which is why there's an array for those xpaths.

```
import bs4
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def download_image(url, folder_name, num):

    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(os.path.join(folder_name, str(num)+".jpg"), 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)


folder_name = '/Users/admin/Desktop/Test'
if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
    os.makedirs(folder_name)


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

search_URL = "https://www.google.com/searchq=minimal+sketches&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjIvvTGkPqAAxUyoekKHQ2CBQ4Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=minimal+sketches&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB46BAgjECc6BwgAEIoFEEM6BggAEAUQHlDyBFiwD2D9D2gAcAB4AIABf4gB5QOSAQM4LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=sNXpZMimAbLCpgeNhJZw&bih=937&biw=1920"
driver.get(search_URL)

a = input("Waiting for user input to start")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0);")

page_html = driver.page_source
pageSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
containers = pageSoup.findAll('div', {'class': "isv-r PNCib MSM1fd BUooTd"})

len_containers = len(containers)
print("Found %s image containers" % (len_containers))

# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]
# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[25] -- The xpath of the non images
# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img -- xpath of first image

for i in range(1, len_containers + 1):
    if i % 25 == 0:
        continue

    xPath = '//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[%s]' % i

    try:
        previewImageXPath = '//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[%s]/a[1]/div[1]/img' % i
        previewImageElement = driver.find_element("xpath", previewImageXPath)
        previewImageURL = previewImageElement.get_attribute("src")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Skipping element %s, XPath not found" % i)
        continue

    driver.find_element("xpath", xPath).click()

    timeStarted = time.time()

    while True:
        potential_xpaths = [
            '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/img[1]',
            '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a/img[1]',
            '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/img[2]',
        ]

        for xpath in potential_xpaths:
            try:
                imageElement = driver.find_element("xpath", xpath)
                imageURL = imageElement.get_attribute('src')
                if imageURL != previewImageURL:
                    break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                continue

        if imageURL != previewImageURL:
            break
        else:
            currentTime = time.time()
            if currentTime - timeStarted > 30:
                print("Timeout! Downloading lower res image to move on")
                break

    try:
        download_image(imageURL, folder_name, i)
        print("Downloaded element %s out of %s total. URL: %s" % (i, len_containers + 1, imageURL))
    except ValueError:
        print("Failed, moving to next")
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue is not with the condition itself but with the structure of the page you are scraping. Sometimes, Google's page structure can change, making it difficult to extract elements by fixed XPaths.

Solutions:

1. Use WebDriverWait to wait for the presence of the element located by the XPath.
2. If the element is found, extract the data-src attribute, which usually contains the URL of the preview image.
3. Click on the preview image and download the high-res image.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to locate the preview images by their `data-src` attribute:

```py
for i in range(1, len_containers + 1):
    xPath = '//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[%s]' % i

    try:
        previewImageElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xPath)))
        previewImageURL = previewImageElement.get_attribute("data-src")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Skipping element %s, XPath not found" % i)
        continue

    # Rest of your code to click on the preview image and download the high-res image
```

This code uses `WebDriverWait` to wait for the presence of the element located by the XPath. If the element is found, it extracts the `data-src` attribute, which usually contains the URL of the preview image.

Comment: hmm oddly, it still stops at the 50th element on the dot, which is really weird.

Comment: By the way, when i say stops at 51, i mean, it runs this error "Skipping element 51, XPath not found", and repeats the error for the rest of the images.